# Linux Iptables Nat with two gateway

Tags: iptables, nat, gateway, forwarding

I got a CentOS server in a DMZ that act as a DHCP and DNS server with the following network configuration:

eth0
IP: 192.168.100.50
SN: 255.255.255.0
GW: 192.168.100.1

Now I added a seconde network interface to act as a special gateway with the following network configuration:

eth1:
IP: 206.55.91.27
SN: 255.255.255.240
GW: 206.55.91.17

With this configuration, I want those 2 scenarios to work:

1. Client in the DMZ get IP from my DHCP with the gateway 192.168.100.1 and they use the dns serveur at 192.168.100.50
2. I assign a static IP to a client in the DMZ with my CentOS serveur as the gateway (192.168.100.50).  IP traffic from the client go to 192.168.100.50 and is nated/fowarded on 206.55.91.27 (second interface on my server)

Is it possible to do this with iptables?  Would it be simpler if instead of 2 interfaces I had 3?  1 for the services on the DMZ (DNS, DHCP), 1 for the gateway and 1 for my external network (206.55.91.27).

Diagram of the [Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhAgG.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you read these yet?  http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html  and http://lartc.org/howto/index.html

Comment: I did but I'm not sure that it will work with this setup.

Comment: I added a diagram of the network.